# How do I use a JS regexp to match a string only if the regexp matches the entire string(no substring)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am on this [FCC challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/reuse-patterns-using-capture-groups/). In this challenge, you are asked to create a regexp to match a string only if it has the same number repeated 3 times with spaces in between. This means that a string with 4 numbers with spaces in between would not count as a valid match even though the regexp below would match it. How could I modify my regexp to match a string ONLY IF it has a specific number repeated 3 times, no more, no less.

```
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /(\d+)\s\1\s\1/; // Change this line
let result = reRegex.test(repeatNum);
```

What should I add into my code to make it valid only if a specific condition is valid for the entire string?

Comment: You can use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end

Comment: I apologize, that method does work. Thankyou very much for your help @CertainPerformance! I have been stuck on this for hours trying all sorts of methods to solve my problem. Yours is both the cleanest and only one that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the string:

```js
const re = /^(\d+) \1 \1$/;
console.log(re.test("42 42 42"));
console.log(re.test("42 42 42 42"));
console.log(re.test("42 42"));
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `\1 \1`

Comment: [Backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Substitutes with the text from the 1st captured group.